# Is there an easy way to generate weighted vertices in graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

There are several ways to include edge weights in graphs, but what about node/vertex weights? I need each vertex to be labelled with a letter and weighted with a number; I cannot find code that does this in a straightforward manner. I have been using the tikz-graph package, but the documentation does not indicate how I could include node weights with labels. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's an example graph with letter labels, but no vertex weights:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Dijkstra]
\Vertices[Lpos=90,unit=2]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
\SetVertexMath
\Edges(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
\Edges(B,E,G,A,E,C)
\Edges(D,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not MSE you know :) Can you give a less technical description of your problem with a MWE?

Comment: Do you want the weight label inside a circle of a node and the letter label outside the circle of a node?

Comment: The weight label would be great if it was on the outside.

Comment: You minimal working example should be compilable. You also need to provide `\documentclass ... \end{document}`.

Comment: could you give us a picture of what you hope to achieve?

Comment: Also: "weighted vertices" is misleading, because it refers to the semantics, instead of the syntax of your vertices. A more appropriate term would be "labeled vertices" or "annotated vertices".

Answer (score 1):

TikZ has a [relatively new](http://gezeiten.org/?q=tikz) library for drawing graphs and using graph layout algorithms to automatically position the nodes. It includes options for styling the nodes and their labels. [Here](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/drawing-graphs/) is a small example. The PGF/TikZ manual has more information. A small tutorial can be found [here](http://eric.emdti.com/simple-graph-diagrams-in-latex-with-pgftikz-3-0/) and a very succinct presentation by Till Tantau [here](http://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/downloads/mitarbeiter/tantau/2012-gd-presentation.pdf).

Comment: To improve this answer and make it more self contained, could you apply the suggestion to the poster's example and provide a complete working document.